# Memory allocation check for different pointer types

Tags: c, pointers, memory, void

I have some structures in my C project and I would like to make a function that checks if allocation was successful. Can I use the void* pointer so I could pass different pointer types as an argument?

```
void memAllocCheck(Structure *container, void *pointer) {
    if(pointer == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, ALLOCATION_FAILED);

        deleteStructure(container);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Is it legal? Is it a good way to deal with memory allocation check?

Comment: you don't need to know the type of the pointer in order to check it for null

Comment: @yellowantphil Yes, we don't need to bother about container - actually I should've deleted it in the code I posted because it has nothing to do with the memCheck function. All I want is to perform deleteStructure before exiting the program.

Comment: I didn't read your question well enough. My non-authoritative answer is that your idea will work and is fine according to the C standard. Don't quote me on the standard though...

Comment: Yes, you can do this. But use `perror()` instead of `fprintf()`, as it has been specifically designed to report errors.

Comment: @yellowantphil Yes I have several structures involving pointers, where I use malloc. And I want to check for every type of pointer I have in my project if allocation was successful.
For ex I do

`Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
TreeElement* element = (TreeElement*)malloc(sizeof(TreeElement));
Node* *arrayOfNodes = (Node**)malloc(ARR_SIZE * sizeof(Node*));`

And I would like to check for every mallocation if it was succesfull, so I would love to use it like that:

`memAllocCheck(container,newNode);
memAllocCheck(container,element);
memAllocCheck(container,arrayOfNodes);`

Comment: Thank you so much guys for answering.

Comment: Better to write a function which allocates it and checks for failure at the same time.